# npm ERR! husky - .git can't be found WINDOWS

Tags: npm, npm-install, husky, angular-calendar, .git-folder

I'm trying to install **mattlewis92's**  [*angular 14.0+ calendar*](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar#getting-started), which suggests the use of the command `ng add angular-calendar`. However when doing so I got an error:

```
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c husky install
npm ERR! 'husky' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
```

I realized that I don't have husky as a dependency so I added it according to [husky's docs](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/).
Unfortunately after installing husky I got a new error:

```
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c husky install
npm ERR! husky - .git can't be found (see https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory)
```

I followed the suggested link above [huksy docs/ Recipes/ Custom directory](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory), but I have no common problem as **package.json** as well as **.git** and **.husky** are all in the same directory level -> in my project's root folder.

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could

### 1. Update your node.js version

This is the accepted node js version found over their website
`Node.js (>=14.19.0 or >=16.9.0)`

So if, you do not have those version -> update it.

### 2. Use a former version

You do not want to update your node.js version ?
Downgrade to the following ->  `angular-calendar: 0.29.0`

### 3. Dirty Workaround

The library cannot install the `calendar-utils`.

Funnily enough, running `npm i angular-calendar` outside an angular project worked just fine

So what you can do.

1. run `npm i angular-utils` somewhere outside an angular project
2. Copy the generated information `node_modules`, `package.json` & `package-lock.json` inside your project
3. run `npm i angular-calendar`
4. Then if you which, `ng add angular-calendar` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, everything was fine except parent folder of the project had `.git`.

Husky found a problem as `.git` in parent folder whereas project in child folder of it.

I removed `.git` from parent folder as git was mistakenly *init* in parent folder.